# php ews, get sent items more info

Tags: php, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, items

I use jamesiarmes/php-ews to connect with Exchange server to get an email list.

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices('[host]', '[username]', '[password]');

$request = new EWSType_FindItemType();

$request->ItemShape = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
$request->ItemShape->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::DEFAULT_PROPERTIES;

$request->Traversal = EWSType_ItemQueryTraversalType::SHALLOW;

$request->ParentFolderIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId = new EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::SENT_ITEMS;

// sort order
$request->SortOrder = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfFieldOrdersType();
$request->SortOrder->FieldOrder = array();
$order = new EWSType_FieldOrderType();
// sorts mails so that oldest appear first
// more field uri definitions can be found from types.xsd (look for UnindexedFieldURIType)
$order->FieldURI->FieldURI = 'item:DateTimeReceived'; 
$order->Order = 'Ascending'; 
$request->SortOrder->FieldOrder[] = $order;

$response = $ews->FindItem($request);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($response, true).'</pre>';
```

I'd like to get sent items:

```
EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::SENT_ITEMS;
```

This script prints

```
  [0] => stdClass Object
(
    [ItemId] => stdClass Object


(
        [Id] => AQAeAGptYXJzY2hhbGwAQGdyb3VwLm1va2F0ZS5jb20ucGwARgAAA9S15wLis8lApRvdnAdC+XoHAC51TyudPmVDoXWXKV00MAYAAAIBCgAAAC51TyudPmVDoXWXKV00MAYAAAIedwAAAA==
        [ChangeKey] => CQAAABYAAAAudU8rnT5lQ6F1lyldNDAGAAAAAB6h
    )

    [Subject] => test
    [Sensitivity] => Normal
    [Size] => 3534
    [DateTimeSent] => 2014-07-03T06:56:17Z
    [DateTimeCreated] => 2014-07-03T06:56:17Z
    [HasAttachments] => 
    [From] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Mailbox] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Name] => [name]
                    [EmailAddress] => /O=GROUP TEST/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=59219DC26E6D463AB22C558CC646227D-name
                    [RoutingType] => EX
                )

        )

    [IsRead] => 1
)
```

So, my question is how can I get an e-mail address for recipient? Is it possible?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Recipients of a Message (and a number of other properites) aren't returned when you use a FindItem request you need to make a GetItem request [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa565934(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa565934%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) on the particular ItemId you want to get the recipients for. If you need to do this for a large number of Items you can batch the GetItems Request eg http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2010/03/16/loading-properties-for-multiple-items-with-one-call-to-exchange-web-services.aspx

Cheers
Glen